Can I hook App Service web apps to sub directories rather than sub domains?
I currently have several web apps in Azure that are on the same domain but under different subdomains.
This works ok but I don't want to add a new sub-domain each time I deploy a new app (e.g. for a new customer).
Current set up:

app1.mydomain.com  points to --> App Service App01
app2.mydomain.com  points to --> App Service App02

I'd like to structure it a bit more simply (for me) using sub-directories off the domain.
e.g.

mydomain.com/app1  points to --> App Service App01
mydomain.com/app2  points to --> App Service App02.

etc.
(Linux based apps)
Is this feasible in Azure?
Thanks in advance.

Is your app  deployed in Linux app service?

Yes, and there are several.

Yes, you should be able to do that by putting an Azure Front Door in front of all your apps and configure routing there.

Be cautious when recommending that https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/c8b1d257-8a26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789

valid, though this can be worked around by using the SignalR Service
